# Anyone experienced issue with Kafka for Blue-green deployments?

Tags: apache-kafka, microservices, kafka-consumer-api, blue-green-deployment

Our Services utilize Kafka to publish and consume messages. We deploy our services using Blue-Green deployment strategy.
Consider below scenario :

```
- Suppose we have App1.0 service in Blue(which is live and taking traffic) currently ,consuming from topic,
 - when we start deploying a new version App1.1, it will get deployed to Green first,so now 
      Green has : App1.1 (not consuming)
      Blue has :  App1.0 (consuming messages)
 - once we switch green to blue , Blue has App1.1 , and green has App1.0.
```

Our issue here is that once the switch happens, our green pods(in which we have older code App1.0) are still consuming messages from that kafka topic . Ideally green pods should now stop consuming from the topic.
We are looking for a solution wherein when we deploy ,our green pods should stop consuming .

Comment: If you want the same consumer group, then there is no such feature that Kafka can provide for this. You'd need to make a locking mechanism around the KafkaConsumer class poll loop that can handle that yourself

Comment: @OneCricketeer Locking mechanism can be a option , also it creates another question - ' How will our service know that's its in Green zone ? As our apps dont know the state of deployment.(i'll research on this :))'
And lastly thank you for your input ! cheers :)

Comment: Assuming you use Zookeeper for a Coordinated Lock, you could try to store a ZNode that contains a JSON list of `[{'version': '1.0', 'active': false}, {'version': '1.1', 'active': true}]`, then work with some metadata like that as apps change and get deployed... Haven't tried personally that way, but worth a try